# Can't read german character from oracle db

Tags: java, oracle

I stored the character "ü" in oracle db with its equivalent uni code value. but when i tried to access the value using java codes, it shows different character "¿". I need a solution for this problem.

Comment: what´s the encoding used for the database? Additionally, did you check if the `ü` is present in the database itself or if it does happen on the java level.

Comment: You're using the wrong character encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong character encoding.

In oracle db you should use for your tables and fields a proper encoding, i suggest you **UTF-8** which is the standard.

Using java codes, you will then get the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

The character is a `non-ASCII` character.

You can either use `ISO/IEC 8859-15` encoding or `UTF-8` character encoding for reading them. Also check if the character is showing correctly in the Oracle DB. It may happen that while inserting the value in DB char encoding was wrong and hence on Java end you are facing this issue.